# Pagination UITableView, setting the content offset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to implement pagination in my UITableView. My cells heights are pretty much fullscreen, code here:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height) - (self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)-20;

}
```

I have set paging enabled in the interface builder however the offset is slightly wrong. I guess this is because it uses the size of the window frame as its offset. Is there anyway I can adjust this to match my table cell heights? Any tips would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

If `TabBar` or bottom of the view is covering the `TableView` cells then use following code in `-viewDidLoad:` method

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
// self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame), 0.0f);
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 75.0f, 0.0f);
```

If you want to present the top of your table view when it appears the use following code in `-viewWillAppear:` method

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0 - self.tableView.contentInset.top);
```

Hope you find your answer